# CATiledLayer: why is adding a drop shadow making it so slow and run out of memory?

Tags: cocoa-touch, performance, xamarin.ios, calayer

I have written a little PDF view which shows PDFs page by page to reduce memory usage. Works fine, however it runs out of memory and becomes super slow (unusabe) as soon as I add a drop shadow to my viewed page. The code of the whole project is below. If you look at the ViewWillAppear() method, you'll see the shadows commented out. Comment it in and the whole thing starts sucking. What is causing this? You can even see it in the Simulator. Just zoom into the PDF and scroll and it'll get stuck. Remvoe the shadow and all is fine.

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System.IO;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
using MonoTouch.CoreAnimation;

namespace iOSTest
{
    public class Application
    {
        static void Main ( string[] args )
        {
            UIApplication.Main ( args );
        }
    }

    // The name AppDelegate is referenced in the MainWindow.xib file.
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            NSUrl u = NSUrl.FromString("http://www.tfl.gov.uk/assets/downloads/standard-tube-map.pdf");
            //NSUrl u = NSUrl.FromFilename ("./big.pdf");
            this.o = new AppDelegate.PdfViewController (u);

            this.o.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height, window.Bounds.Width, window.Bounds.Height - UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height);
            this.o.View.AutoresizingMask = 
                    UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
                    | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
                    | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin
                    | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin
                    | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin
                    | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin;

            window.AddSubview (this.o.View);
            //this.oViewMain.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

            //UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden = true;

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
            return true;
        }

        private PdfViewController o;


        /// <summary>
        /// Previews first page of a PDF.
        /// </summary>
        public class PdfViewController : UIViewController
        {
            public PdfViewController(NSUrl oUrl) : base()
            {
                this.oUrl = oUrl;
            }

            private NSUrl oUrl;
            private UIView oContentView;
            private CGPDFDocument oPdfDoc;
            private CGPDFPage oPdfPage;
            private CATiledLayer oTiledLayer;
            private UIScrollView oScrollView;
            private RectangleF oPdfPageRect;

            public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public override void ViewDidLoad ()
            {
                this.View = new UIView ();
                base.ViewDidLoad ();
            }

            public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
            {
                base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

                // Setup tiled layer.
                this.oTiledLayer = new CATiledLayer ();
                this.oTiledLayer.Delegate = new TiledLayerDelegate (this);
                this.oTiledLayer.TileSize = new SizeF (1024f, 1024f);
                this.oTiledLayer.LevelsOfDetail = 4;
                this.oTiledLayer.LevelsOfDetailBias = 0;
                this.oTiledLayer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
                this.oTiledLayer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
                /*
                this.oTiledLayer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;
                this.oTiledLayer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
                this.oTiledLayer.ShadowOffset = new SizeF (20.0f, 20.0f);
                this.oTiledLayer.ShadowOpacity = 0.7f;
                this.oTiledLayer.ShadowRadius = 20.0f;
                */          

                // Setup the view that is hosted by the scroll view.
                this.oContentView = new UIView ();
                this.oContentView.Center = this.View.Center;
                this.oContentView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin
                    | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin
                    | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin
                    | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin;

                this.oContentView.Layer.AddSublayer (this.oTiledLayer);


                // Prepare scroll view.
                this.oScrollView = new UIScrollView (new RectangleF (new PointF (0, 0), this.View.Bounds.Size));
                this.oScrollView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin;
                this.oScrollView.Delegate = new ScrollViewDelegate (this);
                this.oScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 4.0f;
                this.oScrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.ScrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor;
                // Add the view the scroll view hosts.
                oScrollView.AddSubview (this.oContentView);
                this.View.AddSubview (this.oScrollView);
            }

            public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
            {
                base.ViewDidAppear (animated);

                Console.WriteLine ("Loading PDF: {0}", this.oUrl.ToString ());
                this.oPdfDoc = CGPDFDocument.FromUrl (this.oUrl.ToString ());

                // For demo purposes, show first page only.
                this.oPdfPage = this.oPdfDoc.GetPage (1);

                this.oPdfPageRect = this.oPdfPage.GetBoxRect (CGPDFBox.Media);
                this.oTiledLayer.Frame = this.oPdfPageRect;
                this.oContentView.Frame = this.oPdfPageRect;
                this.oContentView.Center = this.View.Center;
                this.ResizePage ();
            }

            private void ResizePage ()
            {
                // Adjust PDF page to available space. Keep aspect ration.
                this.oScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 0.001f;
                float fScaleX = this.View.Bounds.Width / this.oPdfPageRect.Width;
                float fScaleY = this.View.Bounds.Height / this.oPdfPageRect.Height;
                float fScale = 0.9f * (fScaleX > fScaleY ? fScaleY : fScaleX);
                this.oScrollView.SetZoomScale (fScale, false);
                this.oScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = fScale;
            }

            public override void ViewDidUnload ()
            {
                base.ViewDidUnload ();
                this.oPdfPage.Dispose ();
                this.oPdfDoc.Dispose ();
                this.oContentView.Dispose ();
                this.oPdfPage = null;
                this.oPdfDoc = null;
                this.oContentView = null;
            }

            public override void DidRotate (UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
            {
                base.DidRotate (fromInterfaceOrientation);

                this.ResizePage ();
            }

            public class TiledLayerDelegate : CALayerDelegate
            {
                public TiledLayerDelegate(PdfViewController oParentController) : base()
                {
                    this.oParentController = oParentController;
                }

                private PdfViewController oParentController;

                public override void DrawLayer (CALayer layer, CGContext context)
                {
                    context.SaveState ();
                    context.SetRGBFillColor (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                    context.FillRect (context.GetClipBoundingBox ());
                    context.TranslateCTM (0.0f, layer.Bounds.Size.Height);
                    context.ScaleCTM (1.0f, -1.0f);
                    context.ConcatCTM (this.oParentController.oPdfPage.GetDrawingTransform (CGPDFBox.Media, layer.Bounds, 0, true));
                    context.DrawPDFPage (this.oParentController.oPdfPage);
                    context.RestoreState ();
                }
            }

            public class ScrollViewDelegate : UIScrollViewDelegate
            {
                public ScrollViewDelegate(PdfViewController oParentController) : base()
                {
                    this.oParentController = oParentController;
                }

                private PdfViewController oParentController;

                public override UIView ViewForZoomingInScrollView (UIScrollView scrollView)
                {
                    return this.oParentController.oContentView;
                }

                public override void DidZoom (UIScrollView scrollView)
                {
                    // Override to center PDF page.
                    float fX = scrollView.Bounds.Width > scrollView.ContentSize.Width ? (scrollView.Bounds.Size.Width - scrollView.ContentSize.Width) * 0.5f : 0.0f;
                    float fY = scrollView.Bounds.Height > scrollView.ContentSize.Height ? (scrollView.Bounds.Size.Height - scrollView.ContentSize.Height) * 0.5f : 0.0f;
                    oParentController.oContentView.Center = new PointF (scrollView.ContentSize.Width * 0.5f + fX, scrollView.ContentSize.Height * 0.5f + fY);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess its due to the iOS's dislike of rendering semi-opaque views on the fly. Might also be the same reason that when you add a `UILabel` whose layers have a rounded corner to a `UITableView`, it causes the table to perform like ass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at setting an explicit `shadowPath` on the layer. From [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shadowPath):

> If the value in this property is
>   non-nil, the shadow is created using
>   the specified path instead of the
>   layer’s composited alpha channel. The
>   path defines the outline of the
>   shadow. It is filled using the
>   non-zero winding rule and the current
>   shadow color, opacity, and blur
>   radius.

Also, the OmniGroup has [a blog post regarding drop shadow performance](http://www.omnigroup.com/blog/entry/ipad_drop_shadow_performance_test/) that might help you out as well.

Not sure what it would look like in C#, but in Objective-C (assuming your PDF view is a simple view [i.e., rectangular]) you can use:

```
[UIBezierPath pathWithRect:pdfView.bounds].CGPath
```

`pathWithRect` is a `UIBezierPath` class method (which returns an instance) and `CGPath` is a property/instance method.

Comment: How would an explicit path have to look like?

Comment: Added an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Still I will have to resize the shadow path because my view is zoomable which will make it as slow as it was but thanks for the suggestion. In general it works, but I'll just leave the shadow away for now.